# PostgreSQL deadlock while trying to obtain records for update

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a multiple processes doing some work on accounts in a single table. I have implemented a query which each process uses to lock 100 random unlocked records by setting a value in lock column and returns the locked ids.

```
UPDATE accounts SET locked = now() WHERE account_id in
    (SELECT account_id FROM accounts
              WHERE last_account_info_fetched IS NULL AND locked IS NULL
    LIMIT 100
    FOR UPDATE)
RETURNING account_id
```

And the the process which got a bunch of IDs back from the first query in another transaction does an update and unlocks the record.

```
UPDATE accounts SET last_account_info_fetched = ?, locked = NULL WHERE account_id = ?
```

The problem is that when multiple processes run the first query, it causes a deadlock. How to fix this so that each process gets a different batch of ids without deadlocks?

```
ERROR: deadlock detected
  Detail: Process 3428 waits for AccessExclusiveLock on tuple (16865,68) of relation 10409452 of database 10221183; blocked by process 8628.
Process 8628 waits for ShareLock on transaction 27789140; blocked by process 5340.
Process 5340 waits for ShareLock on transaction 27789126; blocked by process 3428.
```

Comment: Have you tried using `OFFSET` ?

Comment: No, but how would I use it in this case, do you have an example? The processes are running in a cluster, and I don't know up front how many such worker processes will be there, so I can't split up the work up front.

Comment: Why are you doing it this way?  Why 100 at a time, and why not do all the processing in one transaction?  There are various mitigations you can try, but which ones depend on why it is designed the way it is.

Answer (score 1):

How about you add a range limit to each thread so that they don't overlap:

```
UPDATE accounts SET locked = now() WHERE account_id in
    (SELECT account_id FROM accounts
              WHERE last_account_info_fetched IS NULL AND locked IS NULL 
              and account_id >= 0 
              and account_id <1000 
              LIMIT 100
    FOR UPDATE)
RETURNING account_id
```

If you can figure out a way for each thread to have its own range, you shouldn't have this problem.  You could have each thread pick a random number and then only unlock rows in that range, but would still get overlap once in a while in that scenario.

Comment: Yep, this is pretty much the only way to do it and retain concurrency without `SKIP LOCKED` or a controlling task distribution process.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be trying to implement a work queue / task queue or messaging system.

This is harder than you'd expect, as you are discovering.

I suggest using an existing well established one; look into ActiveMQ, ZeroMQ, Celery, RQ, resqueue, ... many other message and task queues.

There's work going on that should make this easier in PostgreSQL 9.5, though: the `SKIP LOCKED` patch, which lets you select the first `n` records not already locked by some other process.

Answer (score 0):

Here`s a good answer: [Avoiding PostgreSQL deadlocks when performing bulk update and delete operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27007196/avoiding-postgresql-deadlocks-when-performing-bulk-update-and-delete-operations)

Here`s how your query would look with the fix:

```
UPDATE accounts SET locked = now() WHERE account_id in
(SELECT account_id FROM accounts
          WHERE last_account_info_fetched IS NULL AND locked IS NULL 
          and account_id >= 0 
          and account_id <1000 
          ORDER BY account_id --that`s it
          LIMIT 100
    FOR UPDATE)
RETURNING account_id
```