# Postgres, update and lock ordering

Tags: sql, postgresql, transactions, locking, deadlock

I'm working on Postgres 9.2.

There are 2 UPDATEs, each in their own transactions.  One looks like:

```
UPDATE foo SET a=1 WHERE b IN (1,2,3,4);
```

The other is similar:

```
UPDATE foo SET a=2 WHERE b IN (1,2,3,4);
```

These could possibly run at the same time and in reality have 500+ in the 'IN' expression.
I'm sometimes seeing deadlocks.  Is is true that that order of items in the 'IN' expression may not actually influence the true lock ordering?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. I think the main issue here is that `IN` checks for membership in the set specified, but does not confer any sort of ordering on the `UPDATE`, which in turn, means that no concrete ordering is conferred upon the lock ordering.

The `WHERE` clause in an `UPDATE` statement essentially behaves the same way it does in a `SELECT`. For example, I will often simulate an `UPDATE` using a `SELECT` to check what will be updated to see that it's what I expected.

With that in mind, the following example using `SELECT` demonstrates that `IN` does not in itself confer ordering:

Given this schema/data:

```
create table foo
(
  id serial,
  val text
);

insert into foo (val)
values ('one'), ('two'), ('three'), ('four');
```

The following queries:

```
select *
from foo
where id in (1,2,3,4);


select *
from foo
where id in (4,3,2,1);
```

yield the exact same results -- the rows in order from `id` 1-4.

Even that isn't **guaranteed**, since I did not use an `ORDER BY` in the select. Rather, without it, *Postgres* uses whatever order the server decides is fastest (see point 8 about `ORDER BY` in the [*Postgres* SELECT](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html) doc). Given a fairly static table, it's often the same order in which it was inserted (as was the case here). However, there's nothing guaranteeing that, and if there's a lot of churn on the table (lots of dead tuples, rows removed, etc.), it's less likely to be the case.

I suspect that's what's happening here with your `UPDATE`. Sometimes -- if not even most of the time -- it may end up in numerical order if that's the same way the rows were inserted, but there's nothing to guarantee that, and the cases where you see the deadlocks are likely scenarios where the data has changed such that one update is ordered different than the other.

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b8e3f/1/1) with the above code.

**Possible fixes/workarounds:**

In terms of what you could do about it, there are various options, depending on your requirements. You could explicitly take out a table lock on the table, although that would of course have the effect of serializing the updates there, which may prove to be too large a bottleneck.

Another option, which would still allow for concurrency -- is to explicitly iterate over the items using dynamic *SQL* in, say, *Python*. That way, you'd have a set of one-row updates that occurred always in the same order, and since you could ensure that consistent order, the normal *Postgres* locking should be able to handle the concurrency without deadlocking.

That won't perform as well as batch-updating in pure SQL, but it should solve the lock issue. One suggestion to bump up performance is to only `COMMIT` every so often, and not after every single row -- that saves a lot of overhead.

Another option would be to do the loop in a *Postgres* function written in *PL/pgSQL*. That function could then be called externally, in, say, *Python*, but the looping would be done (also explicitly) server-side, which may save on some overhead, since the looping and `UPDATEs` are done entirely server-side without having to go over the wire each loop iteration.

Comment: Unfortunately, PostgreSQL doesn't (yet) provide an `UPDATE ... ORDER BY`, which is what we'd need to guarantee this.

Comment: @Craig: The misfortune is of limited reach, since `SELECT .. ORDER BY .. FOR UPDATE` in a subquery achieves the same.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Yep, as the LockRows node occurs outside the Sort node, that should be fine :-) .  Nonetheless, it's a pain that users have to deal with this.

Comment: @Craig: Not saying that an `ORDER BY` clause for `UPDATE` (and `DELETE`) wouldn't be welcome ...

Answer (score 12):

There is no `ORDER BY` in the `UPDATE` command.
But there is for `SELECT`. Use [**row-level locking**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/explicit-locking.html#LOCKING-ROWS) with the [**`FOR UPDATE`** clause](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-FOR-UPDATE-SHARE) in a subquery:

```
UPDATE foo f
SET    a = 1
FROM (
   SELECT b FROM foo
   WHERE  b IN (1,2,3,4)
   ORDER BY b
   FOR   UPDATE
   ) upd
WHERE f.b = upd.b;
```

Of course, `b` has to be `UNIQUE` or you need to add more expressions to the `ORDER BY` clause to make it unambiguous.

And you need to enforce the same order for *all* `UPDATE`, `DELETE` and `SELECT .. FOR UPDATE` statements on the table.

Related, with more details:

- [Postgres UPDATE … LIMIT 1](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/69497/3684)
- [Avoiding PostgreSQL deadlocks when performing bulk update and delete operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27007196/avoiding-postgresql-deadlocks-when-performing-bulk-update-and-delete-operations/27015834#27015834)
- [Optimizing concurrent updates in Postgres](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/68388/optimizing-concurrent-updates-in-postgres)