# Postgres - Deadlock while updating a column that is also part of where clause

Tags: sql, postgresql

My colleague at work and I were wondering if, during an update, a column is being updated while the same column is used in `where` clause, there are chances of deadlock.

For ex:

```
UPDATE EMPLOYEES
SET DEPT_ID = NULL
WHERE DEPT_ID = 13;
```

So if the table `EMPLOYEES` contains about a million records, are there chances of deadlock?

Comment: Absolutely, not. This is a perfectly legitimate update query.

Comment: I don't think there is a chance of a deadlock if only *one* query is running.  Any time you are updating multiple rows, you have a chance that other queries may try to update or delete those rows, leading to a potential deadlock situation, but using the update column in the `where` isn't the cause.

Comment: A deadlock **always** involves _at least_ **two** transactions. A single statement will never "deadlock itself".

Comment: So do you have your answer here?

Answer (score 0):

There is no chance for a deadlock ***at all***. Not only will a single query never deadlock itself in Postgres (see comments), there is also no chance for a deadlock in combination with the same query in a concurrent transactions.

The minimum "requirements" for a deadlock:

- At least two competing concurrent transactions.
- Each of both must lock a resource that one of the others will try to access later.
- Each of both must later try to access a resource locked by the other transaction. So that at least two wait for the other to finish.

In theory *two* concurrent, identical calls like you display have the potential for a deadlock if there are multiple rows with the same `DEPT_IT`. Since there is no `ORDER BY` for a `DELETE`, it can take an exclusive row lock on rows to delete in any arbitrary order. Two identical commands *might* start with different rows and end up deadlocking each other.

In practice, this is not going to happen because both concurrent deletes will take locks in the same order thereby voiding any potential for deadlocks. We would need additional concurrent transactions or more commands in the same transaction trying to lock resources out of order.

But all of this is ***completely* unrelated** to the fact that a column to be updated is also in the `WHERE` clause. (Even if indexes on the column are involved.) Due to the MVCC model of Postgres, it writes a new row version anyway, no matter which columns are actually updated.

**If** you should run into deadlocks involving out-of-order row locks, you can solve it using `SELECT .. FOR UPDATE` with a *deterministic* `ORDER BY` in a subquery:

- [Avoiding PostgreSQL deadlocks when performing bulk update and delete operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27007196/avoiding-postgresql-deadlocks-when-performing-bulk-update-and-delete-operations/27015834#27015834)
- [Postgres, update and lock ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27262900/postgres-update-and-lock-ordering)