# How can two DELETE queries deadlock in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, transactions, deadlock

Among the many things we do with Postgres at work, we use it as a cache for certain kinds of remote requests. Our schema is:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cache (
    key VARCHAR(256) PRIMARY KEY,
    value TEXT NOT NULL,
    ttl TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NULL
);

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS idx_cache_ttl ON cache(ttl);
```

This table does not have triggers or foreign keys. Updates are typically:

```
INSERT INTO cache (key, value, ttl)
VALUES ('Ethan is testing8393645', '"hi6286166"', sec2ttl(300))
ON CONFLICT (key) DO UPDATE
SET value = '"hi6286166"', ttl = sec2ttl(300);
```

(Where `sec2ttl` is defined as:)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sec2ttl(seconds FLOAT)
RETURNS TIMESTAMP AS $$
BEGIN
    IF seconds IS NULL THEN
        RETURN NULL;
    END IF;
    RETURN now() + (seconds || ' SECOND')::INTERVAL;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Querying the cache is done in a transaction like this:

```
BEGIN;
DELETE FROM cache WHERE ttl IS NOT NULL AND now() > ttl;
SELECT value FROM cache WHERE key = 'Ethan is testing6460437';
COMMIT;
```

There are a few things not to like about this design -- the `DELETE` happening in cache "reads", <s>the index on `cache.ttl` is not ascending which makes it kind of useless,</s> (edit: ASC is the default, thanks [wargre](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6244560/wargre)!) plus the fact that we're using Postgres as a cache at all. But all of that would have been acceptable except that we've started getting deadlocks in production, which tend to look like this:

```
ERROR: deadlock detected
DETAIL:  Process 12750 waits for ShareLock on transaction 632693475; blocked by process 10080.
Process 10080 waits for ShareLock on transaction 632693479; blocked by process 12750.
HINT:  See server log for query details.
CONTEXT:  while deleting tuple (426,1) in relation "cache"
 [SQL: 'DELETE FROM cache WHERE ttl IS NOT NULL AND now() > ttl;']
```

Investigating the logs more thoroughly indicates that both transactions were performing this `DELETE` operation.

As far as I can tell:

- My transactions are in `READ COMMITTED` isolation mode.
- ShareLocks are grabbed by one transaction to indicate that it wants to mutate rows that another transaction has mutated (i.e. locked).
- Based on the output of an `EXPLAIN` query, the ShareLocks should be grabbed by both `DELETE` transactions in physical order.
- The deadlock indicates that both queries locked rows in a different order.

If all that is correct, then somehow some simultaneous transaction has changed the physical order of rows. I see that an `UPDATE` can move a row to an earlier or later physical position, but in my application, the `UPDATE`s always remove rows from consideration by the `DELETE`s (because they're always extending a row's TTL). If the rows were previously in physical order, and you remove one, then you're still left with physical order. Similarly for `DELETE`. We're not doing any `VACUUM` or any other operation which you might expect to reorder rows.

Based on [Avoiding PostgreSQL deadlocks when performing bulk update and delete operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27007196/avoiding-postgresql-deadlocks-when-performing-bulk-update-and-delete-operations/27015834#27015834), I tried to change the `DELETE` queries to:

```
DELETE FROM cache c
USING (
   SELECT key
   FROM cache
   WHERE ttl IS NOT NULL AND now() > ttl
   ORDER BY ttl ASC
   FOR UPDATE
) del
WHERE del.key = c.key;
```

However, I'm still able to get deadlocks locally. So generally, how can two `DELETE` queries deadlock? Is it because they're locking in an undefined order, and if so, how do I enforce a specific order?

Comment: What about managing your cache in a connection with autocommit and without transaction ?  (btw, the index is correct, it is used by your dlete)

Comment: I think even if I don't have a transaction, Postgres creates a transaction around every single query, right? And the DELETEs seem to deadlock all by themselves.. (BTW, thanks! I see ASC is the default for indices.)

Comment: The point of the `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` is to enforce a globally consistent order for all lock acquisitions. If two `ttl` values coincide, your row ordering is undefined, and if a `ttl` value is updated, then the ordering, while well-defined, may differ between concurrent transactions. Try `ORDER BY key` instead.

Comment: Thanks, adding `ORDER BY key` makes the deadlocks go away. But in my application, `ttl` values are always pushed 300 seconds after `now()`, which means they shouldn't be affected by the DELETE any more. So while it's true that the ordering may differ between transactions, one order will always be a subset of the other. Similarly, I guess if two records have the same `ttl`, the ordering is undefined, but whatever the behavior is, should be the same in both transactions, right? (I assumed it was physical order.)

Comment: OK, I did more investigation and it seems like the two transactions are deadlocking on two equal `ttl`s, so I guess your "row ordering is undefined" theory is correct. If you make it an answer, I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

You should instead ignore expired cache entries, so you will not depend on a frequent delete operation for cache expiration:

```
SELECT value
FROM cache
WHERE
  key = 'Ethan is testing6460437'
  and (ttl is null or ttl<now());
```

And have another job that periodically chooses keys to delete skipping already locked keys, which has to either force a well defined order of deleted row, or, better, skip already locked for update rows:

```
with delete_keys as (
  select key from cache
  where
    ttl is not null
    and now()>ttl
  for update skip locked
)
delete from cache
where key in (select key from delete_keys);
```

If you can't schedule this periodically you should run this cleanup like randomly once every 1000 runs of your select query, like this:

```
create or replace function delete_expired_cache()
returns void
language sql
as $$
  with delete_keys as (
    select key from cache
    where
      ttl is not null
      and now()>ttl
    for update skip locked
  )
  delete from cache
  where key in (select key from delete_keys);
$$;

SELECT value
FROM cache
WHERE
  key = 'Ethan is testing6460437'
  and (ttl is null or ttl<now());
select delete_expired_cache() where random()<0.001;
```

You should avoid writes, as they are expensive. Don't delete cache so often.

---

Also you should use `timestamp with time zone` type (or `timestamptz` for short) instead of simple `timestamp` - especially if you don't know why - a `timestamp` is not the thing most think it is - blame SQL standard.

Comment: Thanks -- but I already know the problems with the design. My question isn't how to fix the design, but why does this design cause a deadlock? (Also, thanks for the tip regarding timestamptz, but we `SET TIMEZONE TO UTC` on our database; our application doesn't really expose any timestamps except UTC ones.)